# RVM: Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory when running $bundle install command

Tags: ruby, rvm, rvmrc

I'm trying to setup RVM on my mac. When I run `bundle install` in an empty folder (a dummy project folder) I get the following error:

`Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`

Questions:

1. Do I need to copy any gem files to the dummy project folder? If so, what gems, and where from?
2. Do I need to install anything else?

Comment: in which directory you are running the command `bundle install`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Error in red text]

You Just need to check whether **you are currently in the rails app folder** (In most cases) or   double check whether you have **created the rails app properly**.

Here I am trying to execute the command for starting the rails server,

```
bundle exec rails server
```

As you can see since I'm not in that folder it cant locate the required gem to start up the service.

And an Error pops up like below

> Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

To remove just `cd` into the app folder

```
cd YourAPPfolder
```

And run the required rails command again.

You are done. Voila !!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the project directory before running bundle install. For example, after running `rails new myapp`, you will want to `cd myapp` before running `bundle install`